# How to set ForeignKey attribute knowing just the attribute name and related object's ID?

Tags: python, django, django-models

Is there a way to set `ForeignKey` attribute value knowing just the name of the attribute and the `ID` of the `ForeignKey` related object?

I tried to do this using `setattr()`:

```
setattr(instance, 'product', 41)
```

The result is:

```
Cannot assign "41": "MyModel.product" must be a "Product" instance.
```

Comment: `setattr(instance, 'product_id', 41)`